# [Excel ]Connect two excel file in one to many connection

Tags: excel, connection

I have two excel files. In one I have listed all project managers like project manager name, location, languages etc. in another file I have lists of all projects - name , id, ProjectManager name, etc. My task is to connect these files in the easiest way to one file and create a report. Could you please advise how to do it? This is connection one too many. One project manager can have several projects.

Answer (score 0):

These are two different excel files or two different worksheets?

Comment: It;s two different excel files - name1.xlsx and name2.xlsx